# UITapGestureRecognizer fires on iPad but not on iPhone, but it is the same code

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a small problem that should not be...
I am making an universal app for iOS and i have trouble with UITapGestureRecognizer that fires on iPad but no on iPhone.

**UPDATE Start**

I forced the iPad nib on the iPhone and it works! So there is something wrong with  my iPhone nib file, since both nib only contains a UIView and UIScrollView, what could be wrong as anything else is placed using code...

**UPDATE End**

My recognizer is added for a UIView subclass :

h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface POI : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{
    UIImageView *pointBgView;
    float tipHeight;
    float tipWidth;
}
-(id)initWithPointBg:(NSString *)pointBgURL andFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@property (nonatomic) float tipHeight;
@property (nonatomic) float tipWidth;
@end
```

m file :

```
#import "POI.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation POI

@synthesize tipHeight,tipWidth;

-(id)initWithPointBg:(NSString *)pointBgURL andFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToTap:)];
        // Specify that the gesture must be a single tap
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        // Add the tap gesture recognizer to the view
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

        pointBgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pointBgURL]];
        pointBgView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        pointBgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
        pointBgView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
        pointBgView.clipsToBounds = NO;
        pointBgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        pointBgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        pointBgView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:pointBgView.bounds].CGPath;

        [pointBgView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
        [pointBgView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];



        [self addSubview:pointBgView];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        self.tipHeight = 30;
        self.tipWidth = 50;



    }
    return self;

}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
{
    NSLog(@"TAP");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"StartTap");
    return YES;
}

-(void)respondToTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"UITAP");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"POITap"
 object:self];

}
```

This above is the problematic code...

All the NSLogs are fired when testing on iPad, but not on iPhone (simulator or not).

So :

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

not firing...

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"StartTap");
    return YES;
}
```

not firing...

```
-(void)respondToTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"UITAP");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"POITap"
 object:self];

}
```

...is not firing!?

I must says that is use two separate nibs for this app (obviously one for iPad and another for iPhone) and both are EXACTLY the same in term of what they contains...

I added the delegate because it was not working on iPhone so i wanted to see if it could help, no luck...

What in the world could be the cause of such behavior?

Thanks for any help & peace you can bring me :)

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure you have specified the UIView subclass in both nibs?

Comment: Things to check: userInteractionEnabled = YES on the view. View's bounds are within the superview's bounds.

Comment: @JesseRusak, well in the nibs i have a uiView that contains a scrollView. Then by code i add a subview (in the scrollview) that extends uiView in wich i add instance of the class above (POI). In short, i have only two things to hook up in the nib file and both are working (scrollview i mean)

Comment: @jsd, yes i did check this and it is set to YES, so it must be something else...i am really puzzled here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a problem with UIScrollView, even on iPad i wont be able to tap on a imageView if it wasn't visible when the scrollview appeared (out of the visible frame of the UIScrollView).

At least i know i am not crazy :)

Thanks